# Add a custom PHP page with phpBB3?

Tags: php, phpbb3

i want to add a custom php page in phpbb3 .

I follow this guide  https://wiki.phpbb.com/Practical.Add_custom_page ,but cant get work .

If i put my php code in the aboutus.php, it will show before the template and i dont want this .Also i try using includephp myfile.php  in the aboutus_html , but this didnt work . Some help please :(, thanks. I'm using phpbb version 3.0.12 . How can i get this work?

Answer (score 0):

your problem is caused by output to the page in the `aboutus.php` file. This should be used for logic only, with any output that cannot be hard coded passed to the linked template file using the `$template` object